# how we make Riak KV Cluster with security implementation using java client

Tags: java, riak

Can anybody tell how we interact with security enables Riak KV Cluster using java client.

I tried with following java code to interact with security enabled riak cluster, but getting SSLEngine Problem, Below is the java code ......

```
InputStream inputStream = null;
    KeyStore ks = null;
    try {
        inputStream = new FileInputStream("/etc/ssl/certs/rootCA.pem");            
        CertificateFactory certFactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
        X509Certificate caCert = (X509Certificate) certFactory.generateCertificate(inputStream);
        inputStream.close();            
        ks = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
        ks.load(null, "password".toCharArray());
        ks.setCertificateEntry("cacert", caCert);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
synchronized (RiakConfig.class) {
    List<RiakNode> riakNodeList = new ArrayList<RiakNode>();
    for (final String riakServer : riakServerArray) {
    RiakNode node = new RiakNode.Builder()
        .withMinConnections(10)
        .withMinConnections(50)
        .withRemoteAddress(riakServer.split(":")[0])
        .withRemotePort(Integer.parseInt(riakServer.split(":")[1]))
        .withAuth("riakuser", "riakuser", ks)
        .build();
    riakNodeList.add(node);
    }   
    cluster = new RiakCluster.Builder(riakNodeList).build();
    cluster.start();
}
```

suggenst anyone how we do that???

Answer (score 1):

> getting SSLEngine Problem

Please, always provide the specific problem you are getting. "getting SSLEngine Problem" is a useless bit of information.

Based on [this document](http://docs.basho.com/riak/kv/2.2.3/developing/usage/security/java/) it appears you are using the correct steps. Without more information about the security issue you are getting, further help is impossible. Most likely you do not have your certificates set up correctly. The RabbitMQ documentation includes a [comprehensive TLS/SSL troubleshooting guide](https://www.rabbitmq.com/troubleshooting-ssl.html) that can help you determine if your certificates were created correctly.

Additionally, I suggest that you review how the Riak Java Client sets up certificates and then uses them.

This part of the `Makefile` is where certs are imported with `keytool`:

https://github.com/basho/riak-java-client/blob/develop/Makefile#L43-L62

This is a class that uses the key store to create connections for use in tests:

https://github.com/basho/riak-java-client/blob/develop/src/test/java/com/basho/riak/client/core/operations/itest/RiakJKSConnection.java

Answer (score 0):

Achually this is working fine for single node, in cluster i am facing SSL Engine Problem.